# Sticky Footer overlapping; all css is failing

Tags: html, css, footer, overlapping

I had a great footer, until I simplified my design by making `blog` div extend with the `article` div, rather than contain an inner-scrolling feature.  Now, no matter what form of `CSS` I use, the footer will not stick to the bottom of my page.
If you include a great deal of text, either in the `blog` div or the `article` div, the footer will simply overlap the article/blog text, which extends to the bottom of the page.  I know this is a common problem, but I've already exhausted the tips discussed in previous posts, and none of them seemed to work.  Also, I might add, that I normally don't have this problem with my coding.  So this is a ditch effort to see if fresh eyes can find the problem.  The coding below, is my latest attempt to make this work.
Any help is greatly appreciated. It may be a small error, but I'm just not seeing it.  If you can get it to work then good on you! Thanks in advance.

```css
body {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#container {
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: none;
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
}
img {
  position: static;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: auto;
}
#leftcontainer {
  position: fixed;
  float: left;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 20vh;
  padding: 0;
  background: none;
  margin: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
}
#rightcontainer {
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% - 20vh);
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 20vh;
  padding: 0;
  padding-bottom: -10%;
  background: pink;
}
#article {
  positon: absolute;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: blue;
}
#blog {
  position: absolute;
  float: left;
  width: 50% margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: 50%;
}
#footer {
  position: relative;
  height: 10%;
  background-color: gray;
  width: calc(100% - 20vh);
  margin-top: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 20vh;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="leftcontainer">
    </div>
    <div id="rightcontainer">
      <div id="article"></div>
      <div id="blog"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```css
https://jsfiddle.net/jsdu9h0f/3/body{
overflow-y: scroll;
border: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}

#container{
border: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
background: none;
position: relative;
float: left;
}

img {
position: static;
float: left;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: auto;
}

#leftcontainer {
position: fixed;
float:left;
height: 100vh;
width: 20vh;
padding: 0;
background: none;
margin: 0;
overflow: hidden;
border: none;
}

#rightcontainer {
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% - 20vh);
  margin: 0;
  margin-left: 20vh;
  background: pink;
  padding-bottom: 22%;
}

#article{
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 50%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background-color: blue;
}

#blog{
position: relative;
float: left;
width: 50%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
background-color: red;
}

#footer {
  height: 10%;
  background-color: gray;
  width: calc(100% - 20vh);
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: 20vh;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="leftcontainer">
    </div>
    <div id="rightcontainer">
      <div id="article">I had a great footer, until I simplified my design by making "blog" div extend with the "article" div, rather than contain an inner-scrolling feature. Now, no matter what form of CSS I use, the footer will not stick to the bottom of my page. If
        you include a great deal of text, either in the "blog" div or the "article" div, the footer will simply overlap the article/blog text, which extends to the bottom of the page. I know this is a common problem, but I've already exhausted the tips
        discussed in previous posts, and none of them seemed to work. Also, I might add, that I normally don't have this problem with my coding. So this is a ditch effort to see if fresh eyes can find the problem. The coding below, is my latest attempt
        to make this work. Any help is greatly appreciated. It may be a small error, but I'm just not seeing it. If you can get it to work then good on you! Thanks in advance.I had a great footer, until I simplified my design by making "blog" div extend
        with the "article" div, rather than contain an inner-scrolling feature. Now, no matter what form of CSS I use, the footer will not stick to the bottom of my page. If you include a great deal of text, either in the "blog" div or the "article" div,
        the footer will simply overlap the article/blog text, which extends to the bottom of the page. I know this is a common problem, but I've already exhausted the tips discussed in previous posts, and none of them seemed to work. Also, I might add,
        that I normally don't have this problem with my coding. So this is a ditch effort to see if fresh eyes can find the problem. The coding below, is my latest attempt to make this work. Any help is greatly appreciated. It may be a small error, but
        I'm just not seeing it. If you can get it to work then good on you! Thanks in advance.I had a great footer, until I simplified my design by making "blog" div extend with the "article" div, rather than contain an inner-scrolling feature. Now, no
        matter what form of CSS I use, the footer will not stick to the bottom of my page. If you include a great deal of text, either in the "blog" div or the "article" div, the footer will simply overlap the article/blog text, which extends to the bottom
        of the page. I know this is a common problem, but I've already exhausted the tips discussed in previous posts, and none of them seemed to work. Also, I might add, that I normally don't have this problem with my coding. So this is a ditch effort
        to see if fresh eyes can find the problem. The coding below, is my latest attempt to make this work. Any help is greatly appreciated. It may be a small error, but I'm just not seeing it. If you can get it to work then good on you! Thanks in advance.I
        had a great footer, until I simplified my design by making "blog" div extend with the "article" div, rather than contain an inner-scrolling feature. Now, no matter what form of CSS I use, the footer will not stick to the bottom of my page. If
        you include a great deal of text, either in the "blog" div or the "article" div, the footer will simply overlap the article/blog text, which extends to the bottom of the page. I know this is a common problem, but I've already exhausted the tips
        discussed in previous posts, and none of them seemed to work. Also, I might add, that I normally don't have this problem with my coding. So this is a ditch effort to see if fresh eyes can find the problem. The coding below, is my latest attempt
        to make this work. Any help is greatly appreciated. It may be a small error, but I'm just not seeing it. If you can get it to work then good on you! Thanks in advance.</div>
      <div id="blog">I had a great footer, until I simplified my design by making "blog" div extend with the "article" div, rather than contain an inner-scrolling feature. Now, no matter what form of CSS I use, the footer will not stick to the bottom of my page. If
        you include a great deal of text, either in the "blog" div or the "article" div, the footer will simply overlap the article/blog text, which extends to the bottom of the page. I know this is a common problem, but I've already exhausted the tips
        discussed in previous posts, and none of them seemed to work. Also, I might add, that I normally don't have this problem with my coding. So this is a ditch effort to see if fresh eyes can find the problem. The coding below, is my latest attempt
        to make this work. Any help is greatly appreciated. It may be a small error, but I'm just not seeing it. If you can get it to work then good on you! Thanks in advance.I had a great footer, until I simplified my design by making "blog" div extend
        with the "article" div, rather than contain an inner-scrolling feature. Now, no matter what form of CSS I use, the footer will not stick to the bottom of my page. If you include a great deal of text, either in the "blog" div or the "article" div,
        the footer will simply overlap the article/blog text, which extends to the bottom of the page. I know this is a common problem, but I've already exhausted the tips discussed in previous posts, and none of them seemed to work. Also, I might add,
        that I normally don't have this problem with my coding. So this is a ditch effort to see if fresh eyes can find the problem. The coding below, is my latest attempt to make this work. Any help is greatly appreciated. It may be a small error, but
        I'm just not seeing it. If you can get it to work then good on you! Thanks in advance.I had a great footer, until I simplified my design by making "blog" div extend with the "article" div, rather than contain an inner-scrolling feature. Now, no
        matter what form of CSS I use, the footer will not stick to the bottom of my page. If you include a great deal of text, either in the "blog" div or the "article" div, the footer will simply overlap the article/blog text, which extends to the bottom
        of the page. I know this is a common problem, but I've already exhausted the tips discussed in previous posts, and none of them seemed to work. Also, I might add, that I normally don't have this problem with my coding. So this is a ditch effort
        to see if fresh eyes can find the problem. The coding below, is my latest attempt to make this work. Any help is greatly appreciated. It may be a small error, but I'm just not seeing it. If you can get it to work then good on you! Thanks in advance.</div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

<strike>[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jsdu9h0f/)</strike>

Updated [JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jsdu9h0f/3)

Comment: I am still getting the problem, I'm afraid.  Were you able to get it to work with filler text?  I made the changes and filled the "blog" div pretty full, and still got the footer problem.

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure, why, but when I copy/pasted the coding you included the second time, it worked!  Thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

Check this solution with flexbox (you avoid calc()):

```css
* {
  box-sizing: boder-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
html,
body {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#container {
  background: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}
#leftcontainer {
  width: 20vh;
  background: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#rightcontainer {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  background: pink;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
#article {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: blue;
}
#blog {
  width: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}
#footer {
  height: 10%;
  background-color: gray;
  align-self: flex-end;
  margin-left: 20vh;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="leftcontainer">left container
    </div>
    <div id="rightcontainer">
      <div id="article"><strong>Long stuff to test footer</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate nemo, rerum neque. Rem blanditiis error, quo iste similique exercitationem pariatur quam, illum debitis ex distinctio, facere ratione
        alias aliquid minus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quasi nostrum facere esse atque illum eaque magni dolores deserunt aut reprehenderit excepturi a saepe dolor, consequuntur delectus doloremque unde explicabo quod!Lorem
        ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Libero quibusdam accusantium architecto quis suscipit impedit quae quasi magnam sunt totam non voluptates, cum tempora ut aut eligendi molestiae ab aperiam. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur
        adipisicing elit. Cum quibusdam quaerat, iusto natus nulla sequi nisi eveniet dolore, nobis veniam odio impedit maiores nihil vel. Debitis porro eius id similique.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Cupiditate quaerat hic
        nemo, deleniti nulla officiis molestias, maiores rerum. Enim mollitia dolor facere ad modi ea voluptatem quia sapiente perferendis labore! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque beatae excepturi, quis asperiores necessitatibus
        iure explicabo veniam commodi assumenda? Laboriosam magni veniam quod reprehenderit neque magnam explicabo quia, quis, nobis.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Provident blanditiis harum rerum magni fugiat sequi placeat
        saepe maiores vel quisquam, nisi non beatae consequuntur, perferendis laboriosam odit ipsa reiciendis culpa?Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Amet officiis voluptate labore ducimus. Sapiente adipisci ipsa, ratione aliquid
        tenetur consequuntur nulla dignissimos excepturi nihil molestiae placeat libero? Soluta, beatae sint.Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eveniet voluptates et vero mollitia eius, quia ipsa, quas accusantium laboriosam facilis
        iure voluptatum a deserunt earum assumenda fugiat dignissimos consequuntur nulla.</div>
      <div id="blog">blog</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">Footer</div>
</body>
```